# Excel SUMIF and COUNTIFS

Tags: excel

I'm trying to combine two working functions:

```
=COUNTIFS(
'DATA'!$P:$P, $B5,            //P contains a list of names; B is a name
'DATA'!$O:$O, ">="&AG$3,      //O contains a list of dates; AG3 is a date
'DATA'!$O:$O, "<"&AJ$3        //O contains a list of dates; AJ3 is a date, one week in advance of AG3
)

=SUMIF(
'DATA'!$P:$P, $B5,'DATA'!N:N  //P contains a list of names; B is a name; N are a list of times
)
```

How would one add the list of times (from N) based on a name (from B) between two dates from AJ and AG respectively?

**EDIT:
Sorry for the late reply, I work in a school with autistic pupils and time isn't a luxury.**

Hope this makes sense:

DATA sheet

```
A      |B           |C
NAME   |DATE        |TIME
Joe    |2020 08 02  |190
Sarah  |2020 08 05  |80
Sarah  |2020 08 06  |10
Joe    |2020 08 06  |10
Brian  |2020 08 09  |100
Joe    |2020 08 09  |100
Sarah  |2020 08 16  |10
```

OUTPUT sheet

```
A      | B                | C                | D
NAME   | 2020 08 01       | 2020 08 08       | 2020 08 15
Joe    | 200              | 100              |
Sarah  | 90               |                  | 10
Brian  |                  | 100              |
```

I'd like the OUTPUT sheet to calculate total time (from the DATA sheet) between the dates on row one in the OUTPUT sheet.
E.g. Joe has 200 between 2020 08 01 and 2020 08 08 and 100 between 2020 08 08 and  2020 08 15

This part of the formula counts between dates - which works and I need:

```
=COUNTIFS(
'DATA'!$a:$a, $a2,
'DATA'!$b:$b, ">="&b$1,
'DATA'!$b:$b, "<"&c$1
)
```

Between 2020 08 01 and 2020 08 08

- Joe has 2 instance
- Sarah has 2 instances

Between 2020 08 08 and 2020 08 15

- Joe has 1 instance
- Brian has 1 instance

Between 2020 08 15 and 2020 08 22

- Sarah has 1 instance

This next part of the formula collates the times but not between dates - it's collating all time data for a particular name. In essence "Joe" is showing as 300 rather than two separate instance of 200 and 100:

```
=SUMIF(
'DATA'!$a:$a, $a2,'DATA'!c:c
)
```

N.B.
Had to do a quick example here as my excel file is riddled with GDPR.

Thanx for looking,
Sam

Comment: Show some of your data example.

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding your question correctly?

This reads, if the returned count is greater than 0, do the sum, otherwise, return 0.

`=IF(COUNTIFS('DATA'!$P:$P, $B5, 'DATA'!$O:$O, ">="&AG$3, 'DATA'!$O:$O, "<"&AJ$3)>0, SUMIF('DATA'!$P:$P, $B5, 'DATA'!N:N), 0)`